# asp.net User.IsInRole check in whole website

Tags: asp.net

im using asp.net with c#,

I want to check whether a user is on certain active directory group.

Im doing this check:

```
   if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Group"]))
        {

        }
```

The thing is: where do I place this code?
The site has several pages and I want the validation to be on all pages.

Do I put this on the master page?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is one of my answers that will help you with this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550768/how-to-restrict-unlogged-unauthorized-users-from-viewing-web-pages-in-asp-net/12551115#12551115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to do if the user is not in the required role?  Depending on the answer to that question, you could:

- check it in the Master page
- check it in a base Page from which your Page code-behind classes derive
- check it in global.asax, for example in the Application_AuthorizeRequest event handler

... etc ...