# Restrict direct file access of our attachment folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config, generic-handler

We have this website where we also have a visa application module. The visa application module requires the user to create an account. Whenever the user uploads attachments it is saved in a specific folder inside attachments. This specific folder corresponds to a uniquely generated numbers that is assigned to each user.

Now what I need is if the user is not login they should not be able to access the files inside the attachment folders.

How can I achieve that using http handler?

I have this code

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRegistrationID"] != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRegistrationID"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    DownloadFile(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Write("You don't have the rights to access this file.");
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Write("You don't have the rights to access this file.");
                context.Response.Flush();
            }

protected void DownloadFile(HttpContext context)
        {

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
```

But the problem is I'm having a problem configuring it in web config.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of my answers

[How to restrict unlogged unauthorized users from viewing web pages in asp net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550768/how-to-restrict-unlogged-unauthorized-users-from-viewing-web-pages-in-asp-net/12551115#12551115)

This rule is actualy applied to folders, just what are you looking for.